# MYSQL keeps on crashing

Tags: mysql, innodb

earlier I already fixed mysql and it keeps on crashing. what i did was i stopped the mysql server, and deleted ib_logfile1 and ib_logfile0. and edited my etc/mysql/my.cnf and adjusted the size from 32m to 64m this is how my.cnf looks like

```
# INNODB #
innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group      = 2
innodb_log_file_size           = 64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_file_per_table          = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 8M
```

after a while it crashed again. with this error

```
140304 22:25:05 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140304 22:25:34 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140304 22:25:34 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140304 22:25:34  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
140304 22:25:34  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140304 22:25:34  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile0 size to 64 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
140304 22:25:34  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 64 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
140304 22:25:35  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
140304 22:25:35  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44556
140304 22:25:35 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@sqldb' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
140304 22:25:35 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140304 22:25:35 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
```

any advice on what to do to fix this?

Comment: what you pasted is log after MySQL started. Messages before the start would be much more useful

Comment: uhm the thing is theres no error when i start the sql, just getting errors afterwards,